# Nodejs Express: Routes in separate files

Tags: node.js, express

I write my app.js including all the routes in the main file and everything was working well. After my goal was to make the project more clear by moving the routes in a different files but it is not working.
I'm passing an object instead of a middleware function and I don't know how to fix it in the right way.

So this is my app.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var myRoutes = require('./app/routes/myRoutes.js');

...

//parser for getting info from POST and/or URL parameters
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//for log requests to console
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.use('/myRoutes', myRoutes);

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.end('Welcome Page!');
});

//Server Start
app.listen(port);
console.log('server start at port ' + port);
```

And the app/routes/myRoutes.js contains the following code:

```
var express = require('express');
...
var myRoutes = express.Router();

myRoutes.get('/users',function(req,res){
...
});

myRoutes.post('/setup',function(req,res){
    ...
});

myRoutes.post('/remove', function(req,res){
    ...
});

module.export = myRoutes;
```

I also tried this:

```
var express = require('express');
var myRoutes = express.Router();

myRoutes.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res, next){
        res.end('myRoute Get');
    })
    .post(function(req, res, next){
        res.end('myRoute Post');
    });

module.export = myRoutes;
```

But again it seems not passing a middleware function.

Comment: try `var myRoutes = require('./app/routes/myRoutes');` and check whether myRoutes is null or not

Comment: the file is correctly loaded. The problems is related to passing a middleware function instead of an object.

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My second option code

```
var express = require('express');
var myRoutes = express.Router();

myRoutes.route('/')
    .get(function(req, res, next){
        res.end('myRoute Get');
    })
    .post(function(req, res, next){
        res.end('myRoute Post');
    });

module.export = myRoutes;
```

is working fine! I just write it in a wrong way

```
module.export = myRoutes;
```

isntead of

```
module.exports = myRoutes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this is more of additional tips on the question. You main js file would definately need to load a lot of routes and i found importing all of them is a lot of work. Rather use `require-dir` module to load all the routes like

```
const loader = require('require-dir');
var app = express();
var routes = loader('./routes');
for (route in routes){
  app.use("/"+route,routes[route]);
}
```

needless to say define all routes inside `routes` folder and export `Router` module in each one of them like

```
var router = express.Router();

router.get(....);

module.exports = router;
```