# How to use nested-subfloders routing in nodejs express application?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, nested-routes, module-export

I am working on a node project using express. I have some folders in the routes folder which include several .js files having routes. I want to keep the structure this way to keep my code neat & clear. How to require the routes in app.js file neatly?

1. Seeing this, 
   https://github.com/searsaw/express-routing-example/blob/master/app.js,
   I tried simply :

```
const routes = require('./routes');
app.use('/', routes);
```

but it doesn't work & brings my routes into action.

2. Seeing this, I tried the require-dir method too, but it doesn't work as well.
   [Nodejs Express: Routes in separete files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41908680/nodejs-express-routes-in-separete-files)

My folder structure is like :

```
-routes
    -admin
        -login.js
        -CRUD_event.js
        -CRUD_venue.js
     -client
         -login.js
         -CR_event.js
         -CR_venue.js
```

I don't want to mess my app.js file, 
I know all the routes can be required separately but that would be quite of just requiring code in app.js. I want to keep the route directory structure & require them in app.js in the most optimized way possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where I am going wrong. 
This https://github.com/searsaw/express-routing-example/blob/master/app.js actually explains it all. 
In the routes folder, there is an index.js file requiring & using all other routes & then it is exported. It completely solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an `index.js` file in the routes folder, as you are requiring the folder from your `app.js`, otherwise, it wouldn't know which file to look for. In this file (index.js), you need to specify routes for admins and clients and require them as needed.

In https://github.com/searsaw/express-routing-example/blob/master/app.js you can see that in every directory, there is an `index.js` file.

If you do not want to create an `index.js` file, you should specify the file name in the require statement.

Comment: Looks like you found it out yourself!